# HomeForm panel doesn't load a form (ReservationForm) if this call is made from a dataGridViewImageColumn in RestaurantForm dataGridView.. why?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

this is my first time asking something here, so i hope i explained myself decently.
I encountered an issue when i try to load, into a panel, a specific form from a dataGridViewImageColumn. It simply doesn't do anything, not even change the name of a simple label that should be changed even if everything goes wrong.

The debugging seems to work fine, it enters where it is suppoused to, but doesn't act.

I tried to "move" the call from where i need it to a simple button in the homeForm and it works there.. Can someone help me?
code:

(form where the dataGridView is loaded)

```
else if (headerClickedColumn == "Reservation")
                {

                    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = RestaurantDataGridView.SelectedRows[0];
                    string idCurrentRestaurant = selectedRow.Cells["IDRistorante"].Value.ToString();
                    if (int.TryParse(idCurrentRestaurant, out int currentRestaurantID))
                    {
                        Restaurant currentRestaurant = _dataDisplayer.restaurants.FirstOrDefault(restaurant => currentRestaurantID == restaurant.IDRistorante);

                        if (currentRestaurant != null)
                        {
                            _homeForm.LoadReservationForm(this);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

(HomeForm where i have my function to make my panel load the form)

```
 public void LoadReservationForm( RestaurantsForm restaurantsForm)
        {
            this.FormLoaderPanel.Controls.Clear();
            DashLabel.Text = "Reservations Manager";  //this is the label that doesn't even change
            ReservationForm reservationForm = new ReservationForm( CurrentUser) { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, TopLevel = false, TopMost = true, Visible = true };
            this.FormLoaderPanel.Controls.Add(reservationForm);
           
            reservationForm.Show(); 
        }
```

I'm sorry for the "low" quality of the variable names or for the lack of proper code writing, still kinda unexperienced about it (if you have any tips about writing or other things that could help me improve, you're more than welcome).
In the end I simply expect the form "reservationForm" to be properly loaded into the panel "FormLoaderPanel"
Thank you :)